# Client-side javascript error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm trying to create a new Range object in Ace Editor. I've found numerous examples prescribing the following:

```
var Range = require("ace/range").Range;
var newRange = new Range(0, 0, 0, 10);
```

But when I try this I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

I'm loading the Ace Editor JS in a script tag in a Rails view:

```
<script src="/js/ace_editor/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: have you included requirejs file?

Comment: `require` AFAIK is part of node to load a module.

Comment: @AlexChar - yea, most solutions reference Node- but I'm just trying to use this in a client-side Rails setting...?

Comment: @AmitJoki - Ah, this is a require.js thing? I've never actually used that before

Comment: @Yarin hmm hard to say. But from your code you try to use ace editor module. Why is important to use require? You load the script anyway in header of your html if I'm now wrong.

Comment: @Yarin yes.. It seems like you need to include it. http://requirejs.org/ That library only has `require`  method

Comment: @Quentin that example doesn't make use of Range

Comment: @AlexChar if I call new Range(...) without it, it returns a completely different object type- not Ace's Range object

Answer (score 1):

If you are using no-conflict version you need to use ace.require instead of require, since no-conflict doesn't create global require to not conflict with other incompatible implementations of require, that might be loaded on the page.